# Parallel computing using computers in LAN?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I'm writing a C++ project to solve the [Travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) using [genetic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm). Naturally, I'd like to make it faster using a bunch (about 40) computers in the same LAN. The computers are all running Windows XP... So, the question is what are the ways to parallelize it using the given equipment

Update:
You've helped me to narrow my choices down to mpich an Open MPI, so the only question left is should I use boost MPI wrappers for them? Also, can you recommend a tutorial for mpich/OpenMPI?

Comment: Do the computers have a remote shell (SSH) server running? Are they sharing a networked filesystem (drive)?

Comment: I can set up a SSH server if I need it. Yes, they have a publicly accessible drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use some form of communication to synchronize the processes between the systems.  A common API for this type of application is to use [Message Passing Interface (MPI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface).  There are quite a few implementations for MPI/MPI-2 that work on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

MPI is one of the most used standards for such kind of projects. There are many implementations of this standard from different vendors. I think you should consider two of them:

- mpich http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/
- Intel MPI http://www.intel.com/go/mpi/

Another interesting way is to use OpenMP. There are Cluster OpenMP implementations. This solution could be easier to implement, but not so scalable as MPI in some cases.

Comment: Yup. You can find more information here: http://www.hpcwire.com/features/17884424.html http://software.intel.com/file/6330

Comment: @dancsi: OpenMPI is just one of the implementations of MPI standard.

Comment: What I was tryng to ask, is if it is worth considering it (because Intel MPI is a bit expensive for me)

Comment: @dancsi: I've used OpenMPI on windows - it does work reasonably well.